# Android IllegalArgumentException when trying to use PNG in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack, composable

I'm trying to go through the Jetpack Compose tutorial at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial. I am at the step of including an image and I am using the image they provide.

[image: Profile picture]

I have saved it in the Resource Manager. I am calling it here:

```
    @Composable
    fun MessageCard(msg: Message) {
        Row() {
            Image(painterResource(R.drawable.profile_picture),
            "Profile picture"
            )

            Column() {
                Text(text = msg.author)
                Text(text = msg.body)
            }
        }
    }
```

but I am getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG`. I have checked the header bytes of the image, and they are `‰PNG` as they should be. Am I missing something rather obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as it turns out I guess that I copied and pasted it incorrectly. I went back and redid the process of importing it into the Resource Manager, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, The same error was displaying in Preview. But when I run the project, it was running well without any error.

I just `Invalidate caches and Restart`. And the error was gone.

I think It is the error of compose preview. Hope the issue to be solved in next updates.

Comment: thanks, it works. perhaps it's a bug and it's a bit annoying if the error occurs, I have to invalidate it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case like using `gif or any other formate` instead of `image (.png,.jpg,.svg)`

Answer (score -1):

If this still happens then just reduce the size of the image use https://tinyjpg.com/ to reduce image size